# How to change old php site into responsive site

Tags: responsive-design

Please let me know how to convert old php site - www.cnc4milling.com into a responsive web. Site using php and css
Your replies will be very appreciated

Best Regards

Comment: There are two ways: either hire someone to do it, or do it yourself. If you end up doing it yourself, feel free to ask a *specific* question when you get stuck – the Internet is full of tutorials and guides for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as converting a site through a tool, or simple technique.

Seeing that site, it seems like you **may** only rewrite your HTML and CSS code. Try using CSS Flexbox or Twitter's Bootstrap to achieve responsiveness. There are more ways then those I speak of, each with it's own benefits. Study all of those for better understanding of your needs.

And good luck!